# Does Instruction cache store opcode?

Tags: caching, memory-management, cpu-architecture, processor

I'm trying to calculate instruction cache hit rate. I have simulated a cache in my simulator and feed it with PC. I'm wondering if I need to report the hit rate as the number of PCs found in the cache or the number of PCs which are found AND an OpCode field of them are matched?

These question goes back to the nature of Instruction Cache purpose. Is instruction cache being used to retrieve OpCodes? As we have in Branch Target Buffer(BTB) in which we store the branch target. In BTB case we calculate the hit rate once there is the PC hit and also the target matches. ( in more detail: and once the branch predictor predicts correctly and the branch is taken.) I want to know if there is such a thing for instruction cache as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the concept of branch predictor and caches. Branch predictors are used to **predict** the outcome of the branch. If the branch is predicted to be taken then the next PC is taken from the BTAC (branch target address cache). The hit information comes later when the actual branch target and direction is computed. This is where you compare both the predicted direction and outcome of the branch with the actual results. You get a hit if all of them match.

On the other hand caches are used to store data to give quick data access to the CPU. So, you wouldn't need to compare the "opcodes" to get a hit.

Though you would still need to store the opcodes so that you can retrieve them on a hit. To get a cache hit, you would just need to get the tag from the valid cache line and compare it with the current tag. Here tag is nothing but some bits of the PC depending on your cache implementation.